# What would be the set operations of my set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's suppose I wanted to create the states a light switch could be in and the ways I could operate one using a set. The switch looks like this (which is an istock photo from user crrussel):

[image]

Consider a set $L$ of the following elements:

{up, down}

What operation would I use to go from switching up or down? Could it be something like this?

$up + down = down$?

Or would I have to define some operator $switch$ such that it turns element $a \mapsto b$ where $b$ is the other element of the set $L$? Like this:

$switch\ up \mapsto down$

Just trying my hand at understanding a general intuition of sets by creating my own and seeing if my rules hold properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a set $L := \{ U,D \}$ whose elements correspond to the switch being in the up or down position respectively. What you can do is define two functions called "switch up" $SU: L \to L$ and "switch down" $SD: L\to L$. The notation $L \to L$ means that the functions map element from $L$ to elements in $L$. The action of $SU$ is that it will take either element of $L$ and map it to the up position (since if the switch is already up, pushing it upward will do nothing). Similarly the action of $SD$ is that it will take either element of $L$ and map it to the down position. The two functions acting on this finite set can be visualized as

$\hskip{6cm}$[image: SU]

$\hskip{6cm}$[image: SD]

This is simply one of many ways to represent these operations. We could also look at the matrix representations of these operators. If we define the two elements as column vectors $U := \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $D := \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ then we can represent the switch operators as $$SU =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ and $$SD =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ as then $SU(U) = U, SU(D) = U, SD(U)=D$ and $SD(D)=D$ so the operators have the correct action on the elements of $L$. This representation is nice as composing operations corresponds to matrix multiplication, i.e. if the switch is initially in the down position and the operations performed are switch up, switch down, switch down the resulting state of the switch can be calculated as $$SD \cdot SD \cdot SU \cdot D$$ and by the associative property of matrix multiplication you can calculate $SD \cdot SD \cdot SU$ first and then apply it to $D$.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is kind of a loose question, I would say the most natural thing would be to have the operator $switch$ operate on the set, to transform up to down and down to up. More natural though, I would say, is to have the group $\{\text{Leave Alone}, \text{Switch}\}$ to act on the set $\{\text{Up}, \text{Down}\}$ in the obvious ways.

Answer (score 1):

Binary or unary (or other) operations?

For unary operations:  $*:L\rightarrow L$. A unary operation can basically be thought of as a function with $f(x) = *x$.  $|L|=2$ there are $2^2=4$ possible operations.  (there are two possible outcomes for each of the two possible inputs).  They would be $*u = u; *d=u$ (Always switch  up), $*u=u; *d=d$ (Leave switch alone), $*u=d;*d=u$ (Always toggle switch), $*u=d; *d=d$(Always switch down).

For binary operations: $*:L\times L \rightarrow L$.  There are $|L\times L| =4$ and so there are $|L|^{|L\times L|} = 2^4 = 16$ possible operations.  (There are two possible outcomes for each of the four possible pairs).  Each operation can be listed as a list of the four possible pairs and the value returned by combining them.

The sixteen are:

1)$d*d=d;d*u=d;u*d=d;u*u=d$. Or $x*y=d \forall x,y$. This can be thought of as a trivial operation.

2)$d*d=d;d*u=d;u*d=d;u*u=u$.  Or $x*y=u \iff x=y=u$. This can be thought of as "multiplication" with $u\equiv 1; d\equiv 0$.

3)$d*d=d;d*u=d;u*d=u;u*u=d$.  Or $x*y=u \iff x=u;y=d$. This is not associative.

4)$d*d=d;d*u=d;u*d=u;u*u=u$. Or $x*y=x$.

5)$d*d=d;d*u=u;u*d=d;u*u=d$. Or $x*y= u \iff x=d;y=u$.

6)$d*d=d;d*u=u;u*d=d;u*u=u$. Or $x*y=y$.

7)$d*d=d;d*u=u;u*d=u;u*u=d$. Or $x*y = u \iff x=y$.  This can be that as "addition" if $d\equiv 1; u\equiv 0$.

8)$d*d=d;d*u=u;u*d=u;u*u=u$. Or $x*y = d \iff x=y=d$. This can be multiplication with $d\equiv 1$.

... etc.

Comment: 1) For the unary operations (which I think is more what I was naturally inclining to), why are the operations "Always switch up" or "Always switch down" or "Always toggle switch"? Why not "Operation resulting in up" and "Operating resulting in down" and "Operation resulting in leave the switch alone"? Especially "Always toggle switch". Not sure how that's unique and not a combination of up and down operation results. I think my confusion on the matter highlights a key misunderstanding I have. 2) The binary op bit confuses me, such as $d * u = d$. Sounds like first down, switch up = down?

Comment: "Always switch up" = "operation resulting in up".  "Not sure how that's unique and not a combination of up and down operation results. "  Um... you never said an effing thing about uniquess or combinations. But they are unique in that toggle (u->d;d->u),stay(u->u;d->d),up(u->u,d->u) and down(u->d,d->d) are four different things.  ANd they are not combinations as they are conditional dependent.  The binary op is not an operation on one switch.  It's an operation on two switches that results in a single switch result.  It is not what you want at all.